# A function in C++ made being skipped?

Tags: c++, function, cin

I have made a function called pause(). Here is the code for it:

```
void pause(){
    std::cin.sync();
    std::cin.ignore();
}
```

I also use a declaration in front of my code:

```
void pause();

int main(){

}
```

It worked at first, but now for some reason it just skips the function when I call it...

```
std::cout << "Random text. Press any key to carry on...";
pause();
```

EDIT: Unfortunately, when I try it differently, it goes makes me enter something and then I have to press enter. Is there really not a way to make it so that if you press any key (like the ugly system("pause") it immediately carries on? I'll have to make a new thread for this...

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: How do you know the function is being skipped?

Comment: Which compiler are you using and which version. On GCC 4.8.1 it works very well.

Comment: It doesn't execute the function and carries on with the code because I made some text and I called the function for it to pause but i didn't and carried on executing the code after the text. E.g 

cout << "Hi.";
pause();
cout << "Hello.";

The program displays both of the text together ignoring the pause() func.

Comment: @endeil I have a mac so I use xcode v5.0.2

Comment: Did you know ... you can use `ignore` to skip not just a *single character*, but all the rest of the line, if you want. That way you avoid leaving text in the input buffer. Check out the arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is why it's important to post the smallest complete code you can come up with that compiles and runs and shows the problem. Chances are, though, that there's some input done before calling this function, and it's leaving something in the input buffer. So `pause` isn't being skipped, but it returns immediately because of the noise in the input.

Comment: I kind of solved that by doing adding the line

    std::cin.ignore(); before calling the function however it now takes in any response and then you have to press enter anyway...